# Full youtube palylist using curl ( only half list is dispalying using normal curl )

Tags: ajax, curl, web-scraping, youtube, playlist

[click to check how the list is loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzVYY.png)
i am using the following code to curl youtube but it is showing only top 100 videos in playlist how can i show full playlist videos. There are 180 videos in playlist

( i know about API but i want to use this without youtube API)

```
<?php

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1FO3JrU9Zy-A-q8s4FdzgzNVWsIcTx5q');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
 $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
 echo $contents;
 curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

***Which procedure should i follow to get the full playlist ?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my answer.
I need to curl the remaining videos by

1. Firstly Gather information like url, parameters and request type (post/get) from that ajax request.( by clicking on inspect and the click on network leaflet)
2. Generate the same request from your php/curl code and you got it.